# emacs: What is a subtree in org mode? and how do you create one

Tags: org-mode

I searched Google for "emacs org subtree" but couldn't find
any introductory information on this particular aspect
of org mode.
My questions are

- What is it?
- How do I create one?
- If possible, can I use it as a todo list?
- Can I move up/down items using a single key?

Comment: Please have a look at some basic [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+org+subtree&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=emacs+org+tutorial).

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJTwQvgfgMM) for a quick intro to org-mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subtree is a line that begins with more `*` characters than some line above it. Its purpose is just to organize text, the way a paragraph or chapter might work. For example,

```
* Tree
Some content
** SubTree
More content
*** SubSubTree
```

You can move trees, subtrees, and paragraphs with `M-<up>` or `M-<down>`

Org doesn't have a "todo list". It has TODO items, and it has lists. You would make your Tree (or SubTree) a TODO item but adding `TODO` between the `*` character(s) and the name.

You make lists with `+` or `-`, and these can optionally have checkboxes attached:

```
+ List Item
+ Another Item
```

Or

```
+ [ ] List item w/ checkbox (unchecked)
+ [X] List item w/ checked checkbox
```

Comment: It will help tremendously to read through the few few chapters in the Info manual for org-mode that ships with emacs: `C-h i g (Org)`. It's also available online: http://orgmode.org/manual/